# Настройка доверительных отношений между доменами

Tags: windows, сервер, администрирование

Между двумя доменами (Windows Server 2008R2 и Windows Server 2012) установлено двустороннее транзитивное доверительное отношение. 
Каким образом можно добавить пользователя из одного домена в группу администраторы другого домена? 
Можно ли после установки доверительных отношений подключаться к локальным дискам компьютерам из другого домена без логина и пароля?

Comment: Вообще - да. Я из учётки одного домена рулю gpo другого. Как сделано - хз, делал не я. Попробую дёрнуть старшего коллегу.

Comment: Будет замечательно

Comment: Ответил. Цитирую:
[16:50:38] <*@gmail.com> Тут инструкции не нужны, доверие он уже установил.

1. Каким образом можно добавить пользователя из одного домена в группу администраторы другого домена?
можно, если группа локальная в домене.
2. Можно ли после установки доверительных отношений подключаться к локальным дискам компьютерам из другого домена без логина и пароля?
можно, прописав учетки из другого домена в доступе к ресурсам , либо включив в соотв группы домена.
[16:50:58] <*@gmail.com> ну и человеку стоит почитать за группы в АД и их типы и зачем чего используют